# Restrict SSL access for some paths on a apache2 server

Tags: apache, https

I wanted to allow access to www.mydomain.com/**login** through ssl only.
E.g.: Whenever someone accessed **http**://www.mydomain.com/**login**, I wanted him to be redirect to **https**://www.mydomain.com/**login** so it's impossible for him/her to access that site without SSL.

**I accomplished this** by adding the following lines to the virtual host for www.mydomain.com on port 80 in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^/login(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/login$1 [L,R]
RewriteLog      "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
```

Now, I want to **restrict using SSL** for www.mydomain.com.
That means, whenever someone accessed **https**://www.mydomain.com, I want him to be redirected to **http**://www.mydomain.com (for performance reasons).

I tried this by adding the following lines to the virtual host of www.mydomain.com on port 443 in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl`:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule     ^/(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]
RewriteLog      "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
```

But when I now try to access www.mydomain.com/**login**, I get an error message that the server has caused **to many redirects**.
That does make sense. Obviously, the two RewriteRules are playing ping-pong against each other.

How could I work around this?

Comment: What amount of performance boost do you expect to get from this?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(login) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1

RewriteCond $1 !^(login) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L]
```

I hope(!) that works - put it in .htacess or, if using vhosts, the first part goes in the normal vhost and the second bit goes in the ssl vhost.

No need to specify 80/443 to pattern match (LOGIN or login) in the URL and force to the SSL (or not if there is no match).

*Okay, did not work*

Added bit:

```
 RedirectMatch (?i)\/login https://www.example.com/login
```

In practice (depends on CMS) all your site links will be http anyway so you should only need the one RedirectMatch.

Comment: Hm, that didn't do the trick. The first Cond+Rule worked but the 2nd one doesn't work. `http://www.mydomain.com/login` won't be redirected to `https://www.mydomain.com/login`

Comment: Sorry I haven't got a spare SSL site to test with right now. How about RedirectMatch? Just before your existing code for redirecting from https to http, try RedirectMatch  - see updated answer...

Comment: Now, this is strange. I added the RedirectMatch to sites-available/default. When I go to `http://www.mydomain.com/login`, then I get first redirected to `https://www.mydomain.com/login`, then it jumps to `http://www.mydomain.com//login` and displays an error message that to many redirects occured.